# How can I add Windows Networking events to my custom wprp file?

Tags: trace, hololens, wpr

I'm trying to capture an etl trace on the HoloLens with my own events, and some generic networking events. Using WPR on my PC, I can choose `Networking I/O activity`, which will show events like `Microsoft-Windows-TCPIP` when I analyze in WPA. I can't figure out how to see these events on a HoloLens, or successfully put them in my wprp file.
I've tried the following with no success, even on Windows. My own events work fine.

```
    <EventProvider Id="Microsoft.Windows.TCPIP" Name="2F07E2EE-15DB-40F1-90EF-9D7BA282188A"/>
...
    <EventProviderId Value="Microsoft.Windows.TCPIP"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an WPRP file that captures "`Microsoft-Windows-TCPIP`" and "`Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Network"` events.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WindowsPerformanceRecorder Version="1.0" Author="MagicAndre1981" Copyright="MagicAndre1981" Company="MagicAndre1981">
  <Profiles>
    <SystemCollector Id="SystemCollector" Name="NT Kernel Logger">
      <BufferSize Value="1024" />
      <Buffers Value="512" />
    </SystemCollector>
    <EventCollector Id="EventCollector_UserModeEvents_Session" Name="UserModeEvents_Session">
      <BufferSize Value="1024" />
      <Buffers Value="512" />
    </EventCollector>
    <SystemProvider Id="SystemProvider">
      <Keywords>
        <Keyword Value="ProcessThread" />
        <Keyword Value="Loader" />
        <Keyword Value="SampledProfile" /> 
        <Keyword Value="Interrupt"/>
        <Keyword Value="DPC"/>
        <Keyword Value="ReadyThread" />
        <Keyword Value="CSwitch" /> 
        <Keyword Value="NetworkTrace" />
      </Keywords>
      <Stacks>
        <Stack Value="SampledProfile" /> 
        <Stack Value="CSwitch" />   
        <Stack Value="ReadyThread" /> 
        <Stack Value="ImageLoad" /> 
        <Stack Value="ImageUnload" />  
      </Stacks>
    </SystemProvider>
    <EventProvider Id="NetworkingCorrelation" Name="Microsoft-Windows-Networking-Correlation" Level="5" Stack="true">
          <Keywords>
            <Keyword Value="0x7FFF0000000F"/>
          </Keywords>
    </EventProvider>
    <EventProvider Id="KernelNetwork" Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Network" Level="5" Stack="true" NonPagedMemory="true"/>
    <EventProvider Id="TCP" Name="Microsoft-Windows-TCPIP" Level="5" Stack="true" NonPagedMemory="true">
       <Keywords>
        <Keyword Value="0x0000000400000000"/>
      </Keywords>
    </EventProvider>
    <Profile Id="NetworkProfile.Verbose.File" Name="NetworkProfile" Description="Network Profile" LoggingMode="File" DetailLevel="Verbose">
      <Collectors>
        <SystemCollectorId Value="SystemCollector">
          <SystemProviderId Value="SystemProvider" />
        </SystemCollectorId>
        <EventCollectorId Value="EventCollector_UserModeEvents_Session">
          <EventProviders>
            <EventProviderId Value="NetworkingCorrelation" />
            <EventProviderId Value="KernelNetwork" />
            <EventProviderId Value="TCP" />
          </EventProviders>
        </EventCollectorId>
      </Collectors>
    </Profile>
    <Profile Id="NetworkProfile.Verbose.Memory" Name="NetworkProfile" Description="Network Profile" Base="NetworkProfile.Verbose.File" LoggingMode="Memory" DetailLevel="Verbose" />
  </Profiles>
  <TraceMergeProperties>
    <TraceMergeProperty Id="BaseVerboseTraceMergeProperties" Name="BaseTraceMergeProperties" Base="">
      <FileCompression Value="true" />
      <CustomEvents>
          <CustomEvent Value="ImageId"/>
          <CustomEvent Value="BuildInfo"/>
          <CustomEvent Value="VolumeMapping"/>
          <CustomEvent Value="EventMetadata"/>
          <CustomEvent Value="PerfTrackMetadata"/>
          <CustomEvent Value="NetworkInterface"/>
      </CustomEvents>
    </TraceMergeProperty>
  </TraceMergeProperties>
</WindowsPerformanceRecorder>
```

Run it via `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\wpr.exe" -start network.wprp` and next `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\wpr.exe" -stop NetworkData.etl`

Comment: On HoloLens you use the Device Portal's "Performance Tracing" page, rather than wpr, but all I needed was a functional wprp. Thanks!